# Coset of subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra

We are given the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_8$ , an element $a$ of $G$ and a non-trivial subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $\Sigma=\{a,5 \}$ is a coset of $H$ in $G$. Then $a$ is one of these numbers:

$$7,0,5,6,1.$$

I think that $a$ is $5$ since a coset contains only numbers that are multiple the one to the other, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not right. All cosets have the same number of elements. So, if $\Sigma$ only has a single element, all other cosets have a single element too and that can only happen if $H=\{0\}$. But we are assuming that $H$ is a non-trivial subgroup.

**Hint:** The answer is $a=1$. Can you prove it?

Comment: $\left|\Sigma\right|=1$ only happens when $H=\{0\}$, not when $H=G$. So for $a=5$ we have a coset of the trivial subgroup.

Comment: @Christoph I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the intermediate steps I would do to get through your problem:

1. How many elements does $H$ have?
2. Which subgroups of $G$ have that many elements?
3. For each of those subgroups, what are all its cosets?
4. Which of those cosets contain $5$?
5. What other elements are together with $5$ in any of those cosets?